# Prove that , any primitive root $r$ of $p^n$ is also a primitive root of $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For an odd prime $p$, prove that any primitive root $r$ of $p^n$ is also a primitive root of  $p$

So I have assumed $r$ have order $k$ modulo $p$ , So $k|p-1$.Then if I am able to show that $p-1|k$ then I am done .But I haven't been able to show that.Can anybody help me this method?Any other type of prove is also welcomed.

Comment: Why does $p$ have to be odd?

Comment: Look at Theorem 4.4 of http://math.arizona.edu/~savitt/mathcamp/1999/primitive_roots.pdf

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For any $a$ relatively prime to $p^n$, there is an integer $k$ such that $r^k\equiv a \pmod{p^n}$ and hence such that $r^k \equiv a\pmod{p}$. Thus $r$ is a primitive root of $p$.

Comment: +1 This explains that the statement is really obvious. In fact the argument is even shorter, the first part after "That means.." doesn't seem to state anything new

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: It started as very short. I added "that means $\dots$ and let r be $\dots$ for padding.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I am unable to understand the answer of Andre, can you please ellaborate in a bit detail.

Comment: @TimGreen: First you must understand the definition of primitive element$~r$ modulo$~m$: every number relatively prime to $n$ is congruent to some power $r^k$ modulo$~m$. If this holds for $m=p^n$, then for numbers relatively prime to$~p$ (which are the same ones as those relatively prime to$~m$), they are _a fortiori_ congruent to the same power $r^k$ modulo$~p$. See also the answer by Bill Dubuque.

Answer (score 14):

Note that an integer $r$ with $\gcd(r,p)=1$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$ when the smallest $b$ such that $r^b\equiv1\bmod p^k$ is $b=p^{k-1}(p-1)$.

Suppose that $r$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$, so there is some $b<p-1$ such that $r^b\equiv 1\bmod p$.

> In other words, there is some integer $t$ such that $r^b=1+pt$.

Then of course we have that $p^{n-1}b<p^{n-1}(p-1)$, and 
$$r^{p^{n-1}b}\equiv 1\bmod p^n$$
because of

> the binomial theorem.

(mouse over to reveal spoilers)

Answer (score 11):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ \ \   \rm a\ \ is\,  \ coprime\, \ to\ \ {\bf\color{#C00}p}\,\  &\Longrightarrow&\rm\ \ \ a\ \ is\  \ coprime\ \ to\ \ {\bf\color{#90f}{p^n}}\\ 
& & \qquad\qquad{ \Downarrow}\\  
\smash{\rm r^k\equiv a\ \ (mod\,\ {\bf\color{#C00}p})}\, &\smash{\overset{\ \ \rm\color{#0a0}{CP}}\Longleftarrow}&\rm  \smash{\exists\,k\!:\ r^k\equiv a\ \ (mod\,\ {\bf\color{#90f}{p^n}})}
\end{eqnarray}$

where we employed the result  $\,\rm \color{#0a0}{CP} = $ [Congruences *Persist* mod factors of the modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3236473/242).

Answer (score 3):

**Exercise**: If $X$ is a generating set for a group $G$ and $\phi:G\to H$ a homomorphism, then $\phi(X)$ is a generating set for the image of $G$ under $\phi$; in particular this means that if $\phi$ is surjective/onto then $\phi(X)$ is a generating set for $H$.

Now consider $G=(\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z)^\times$ and $H=(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ with $\phi$ the mod $p$ map (see that it's well-defined and onto!) with a singleton generating set $X=\{a\}$ for $G$.

Answer (score 0):

If r is a primitive root of prime p, we can show that either r is a primitive root of $p^2$ or (r+c.p) is a primitive root of $p^2$ where (c,p)=1.

We can also show that if g is a primitive root of both p and $p^2$, it is also a primitive root of $p^k$  where k is a natural number.

Clearly, there exists one r+c.p where p|c or  (c,p)=1 which is a primitive root of both p and $p^2$ =>r+c.p is a primitive root of $p^k$  where k is a natural number.

Each of $\phi(p-1)$ primitive root of p, will have associated (p-1) primitive roots which are congruent(mod p), but in-congruent(mod $p^2$)   of $p^2$, p(p-1) primitive roots  of $p^3$ and $p^{k-2}(p-1)$ primitive roots  of $p^k$ where k≥3.

Each primitive root of $p^k$ will be associated to p primitive roots of $p^{k+1}$ where k > 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227199/order-of-numbers-modulo-p2/229918#229918), if $ord_{(p^k)}a = d$  where k is a natural number, we can show that  $ord_{(p^{k+1})}a = d$ or $pd$

Now, if r is a primitive root of $p^{k+1}  => ord_{(p^{k+1})}a = \phi(p^{k+1})=p^k(p-1)$

=>$ ord_{(p^{k})}a = p^k(p-1)\ or\ p^{k-1}(p-1) $

=>But, $ ord_{(p^{k})}a ≤\ \phi(p^k) =p^{k-1}(p-1)$

=>$ ord_{(p^{k})}a = p^{k-1}(p-1)=\phi(p^k) $ => r is a primitive root of $p^k$  for all natural number k≥1

Comment: Excuse me, can you explain more about why $ord_{(p^{k+1})}a = pd$? Thanks.

Comment: @puresky, please find the rectified answer.Thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Let the order of $r$ modulo $p$ be $k$ . So,
$$r^k\equiv_p 1$$
which means
$r^k = 1 + ap\, \,$  where  $\, \,p \nmid a$

Now, raise both sides to power $p$ and use binomial theorem to get
$$ r^{pk} \equiv_{p^2} 1$$

Repeat this $n-2$ more times to get
$$ r^{p^{n-1}k} \equiv_{p^n} 1$$
But $r$ is a primitive root of $p^n$, so, $$\phi(p^n) \mid p^{n-1}k$$
where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. Thus, we have

$$p-1 \mid k \Rightarrow k = p-1$$