# prove that $(1+pt)^{p^{r-1}} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^r}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, binomial-theorem, primitive-roots

I need to prove that $(1+pt)^{p^{r-1}} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^r}$

the original question is this:

[Prove that , any primitive root $r$ of $p^n$ is also a primitive root of $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170648/prove-that-any-primitive-root-r-of-pn-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-p)

and I'm following the second answer there. 
I'm trying to use the binomial theorem and having hard time..

any help will be appriciated

Comment: What happens when you expand $(1+pt)^{p^{r-1}}$ with the binomial theorem? Try writing $(1+x)^n$ then substitute $x=pt$ and $n=p^{r-1}$.

Comment: You could go by induction on $r$- the case $r=1$ is easy.

Comment: i tried both ways. Thomas when i try i'm stuck with the denominators. I understand each number in the sum has $p^r$ in it but it is multiplied by a fraction . and Geoff I couldn't make it by induction. thanks anyway

Comment: No, it is not multiplied by a fraction, $\binom{p^r}{i}$ is always an integer. @user2993422

Comment: but i need to use the numerator to get p^r so im not sure it stays an int after that

Comment: The answer by Thomas Andrews indicates how to make the induction work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good lemma to try to prove. If $s\geq 1$ then:

$$\left(1+kp^s\right)^p\equiv 1\pmod {p^{s+1}}$$

This will let you prove the result above by induction.