# If primitive root modulo $mn$, then primitive root modulo $m$ and $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Let $a$ be a primitive root modulo $mn$. Show that $a$ is also primitive root modulo $m$ and $n$.
Showing $(a,mn)=1\Longrightarrow (a,m)=(a,n)=1$ is not a problem. The problem is showing $a^{\varphi (m)} \equiv 1\pmod{m}$ where $\varphi (m)$ is the least natural number for which the congruence holds.
Initial thought:
Let $A :=\{x|a^x\equiv 1\pmod{m}\}\subset\mathbb{N}$, obviously $A\neq\emptyset$ so it contains the smallest element $r$. Must show that $r=\varphi (m)$. Supposing for a contradiction that $r<\varphi (m)$ I would need it somehow to contradict the fact that
$$a^{\varphi (mn)}\equiv 1\pmod{mn} $$
where $\varphi (mn)$ is the least for which said congruence holds.

How should one go about finding a contradiction?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170648/prove-that-any-primitive-root-r-of-pn-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assume that it is not a primitive root $\pmod m$. Then we have that there exists such $r < \phi (m)$  $$a^r \equiv 1 \pmod m$$

Now use that $$\phi (mn) = \phi (m)\phi (n) \frac{ d}{\phi (d)} \ge \phi(m) \phi (n)> r \phi (n)$$

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function-varphi-mn-varphi).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? How do you get a contradiction?

Comment: @CalvinLin $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ while $a^r \equiv 1 \pmod m$. Thus $a^{r\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$, $a^{r\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$. But I think I made a mistake here, as the above two congruences do not necessarily imply $a^{r\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod {mn}$. I'll look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

Because a primitive root modulo $mn$ exists, it is necessary and sufficient that $mn\in\{2,4,p^k,2p^k\}, p>2, k\in\mathbb{N}$. The interesting cases are $mn\in\{p^k,2p^k\}$.

1. Let $mn=p^k$ and $x$ a primitive root modulo $p^k$. It follows that $x$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. Then, modulo $p^2$, at least one of $x$, $x+p$ is a primitive root. It turns out $x$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$, for otherwise $x$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$ and therefore not a primitive root modulo $p^k$.
   Provided $x$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$, it's also a primitive root modulo $p^r,r>2$.
2. Let $mn=2p^k$. The only interesting case is $(m,n)>1$ that is $m=2p^s$ and $n=p^t$ such that $s+t=k$. The assertation holds for $n$ and consequently for $m$, otherwise we would have $r<\varphi (2p^s) =\varphi (p^s)$:
   $$x^r\equiv 1\pmod{2p^s}\Longrightarrow x^r\equiv 1\pmod{p^r} $$
   which then, in turn, implies $x$ is not a primitive root modulo $p^k$ and consequently not a primitive root modulo $2p^k=mn$.