# Primitive Roots modulo n, and modulo d, where d|n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For any number $n$, if a prime $p$ is a primitive root modulo $n$, then is $p$ also a primitive root modulo $d$ where $d|n$ ?

Comment: What is a primitve root? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170648/prove-that-any-primitive-root-r-of-pn-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-p